# Jenkins service does not start automatically

Tags: jenkins

I am using Jenkins as CI from the past one year. But sometimes the service does not start automatically even it was configured as "Automatic" in windows services. And there was no any error or warning logged in event viewer. It is very crazy why it happens like this. Is there any configuration to be done to avoid such case?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a very similar situation and was only able to get a successful restart after opening up connectivity to `http://178.255.83.1:80`. This seems to be a [OCSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_Certificate_Status_Protocol) server, so the traffic seems legitimate.

I'm not sure if it's actually the issue you were having, but it might be something to look at.